# How can I create a view that spans multiple databases?

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have three databases named `exayear2011`, `exayear2012`, and `exayear2013`. They all have the same schema, but the data is different for each year.

I want to create a view that gets data from `table1` in all three databases with `UNION ALL`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4):

That isn't that hard to do.  A simple view using the three part names of the tables will do it.

```
CREATE VIEW YourView AS
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM exayear2011.dbo.table1
union all
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM exayear2012.dbo.table1
union all
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM exayear2013.dbo.table1
```

Comment: And I don't know if this applies to 2000, but in newer versions, you can include a constant in each part to help the optimizer know which tables to use: `SELECT ..., 2011 AS [Year] FROM exayear2011...` If you filter on that column when querying the view, SQL Server will only use the appropriate base tables. (I have no idea how this behaves with inequalities or BETWEEN.)